# Firebase show NoSuchMethodError after add it using assistant

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I want to use Firebase Remote Config in my app. 
I create new project in Android Studio, and run Tools - Firebase assistant as documentation suggest.
In creates app on `console.firebase.google.com` and add next settings to my root `build.gralde`: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` and to app `build.gralde`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
…
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.0'
```

Than I add to my MainActivity:

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch();
```

When I run app it crashes with log on the `fetch()` command:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GoogleApiHandler
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzz(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; 
    in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; 
    or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' 
    appears in /data/app/my.packagename-1/base.apk)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzbd(Unknown Source)
```

I tried ti disable Instant run and gradle clear, but still have this issue. How to fix it?

**UPD:** I figure out that if I move line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` from the second to the last line in app `build.gralde` this fixes an issue, but why?

Comment: Yes, moving the "apply" line to the last line solved the problem for me too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know. Therefore you didn't include the full code. I see it this way:
At first you create an instance like this

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
```

Then you set the configs for development

```
FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings configSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
            .setDeveloperModeEnabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .build();
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(configSettings);
```

Then you set defaults     mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(R.xml.remote_config_defaults);

The XML file has to be located in res/XML

You do the fetching and inside the Listener you activateFetched()

```
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch Succeeded",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // After config data is successfully fetched, it must be activated before newly fetched
                        // values are returned.
                        mFirebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch Failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    displayWelcomeMessage();
                }
            });
```

You get the values inside displayWelcomeMessage() which has to be inside the Listener, it will get the values then finish fetching otherwise (you are gonna be screwed up by async)

I hope I answered and answered correctly

By the way all the sample code is here https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/config/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/config/MainActivity.java

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I already solved an issue, see the last sentence in my question.